# One-line answer reputation privilege

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation

I found a [one-line answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/174469) to [Equivalent of layer.redraw(true) in OpenLayers 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116490) which is bang on the money. The poster who answered has already a fairly good reputation and knows what he or she is talking about.

It's not the accepted answer since the post was already answered before.

There is comment about the length of the answer being short.

[image]

It should be a reputation privilege to have the comment about one-line answers removed.

Say a poster with several thousand points reputation who makes a one-line answer will not have the default one-line answer comment displayed.

Comment: In this case it was automatically [by the stack exchange system] flagged as a short answers, we encourage full answer throughout stack exchange sites. Please flag it for moderators attention.

Comment: This may be relevant from Meta SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the motivation of this request is good, I am concerned about unintentional bad consequences.  On plenty of sites a few people come along and build relatively large reputations quickly either through posting a great many *questions* or a great many *mediocre* answers.  In neither case should the accumulation of reputation allow them unilaterally to post throw-away or drive-by answers.  In fact, nobody should be given any slack concerning the quality of their posts just because they have high reputations, clearly know what they are doing, or are moderators: we are all held to the same standards.

You might not know that the post notice is not placed there automatically: a moderator has to choose to do it, usually in response to a flag indicating the answer needs elaboration.  Sometimes you will see a notice that does not appear necessary (often because the answer was improved after the notice was put up--moderators are not notified when this happens).  Please just flag such posts to have the notice removed.

Answer (score 1):

The cited answer is one to which I applied the post notice and, in its current one line state, I think it should be left there.

I almost always process the system generated flags on one-line answers by applying a post notice, irrespective of who the poster is, so that it is the answer, rather than its poster, that is being assessed.

The exception is when I see a one-line answer that I know can, if I have time to, be expanded via an edit.

For example, a one line answer to a question about which tool to do some ArcGIS polygon overlay operation might be:

> Try using the Union tool

which would normally get a post notice for being a one-liner, even though perfectly correct.

However, it only needs a simple edit to become something like:

> Try using the [Union](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) tool which:
>
> *Computes a geometric union of the input features. All features and their attributes will be written to the output feature class.*

With minimal effort, it changes the answer from being a bare instruction, to one wrapped with a summary of what it does and a link to where more information about it can be found.

I would recommend doing something similar to any one-liners that you see with post notices, if they are within your area of expertise, then flag asking for removal of the no longer applicable post notice.